# Multi-threaded concurrent Capybara requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

My API allows users to buy certain unique items, where each item can only be sold to one user.  So when multiple users try to buy the same item, one user should get the response: *ok* and the other user should get the response *too_late*.

Now, there seems to be bug in my code. A race condition. If two users try to buy the same item at the same time, they both get the answer *ok*. The issue is clearly reproducable in production. Now I have written a simple test that tries to reproduce it via rspec:

```
context "when I try to provoke a race condition" do
  # ...

  before do
    @concurrent_requests = 2.times.map do
      Thread.new do
        Thread.current[:answer] =  post "/api/v1/item/buy.json", :id => item.id
      end
    end

    @answers = @concurrent_requests.map do |th|
      th.join
      th[:answer].body
    end
  end

  it "should only sell the item to one user" do
    @answers.sort.should == ["ok", "too_late"].sort
  end
end
```

It seems like does not execute the queries at the same time. To test this, I put the following code into my controller action:

```
puts "Is it concurrent?"
sleep 0.2
puts "Oh Noez."
```

Expected output would be, if the requests are concurrent:

```
Is it concurrent?
Is it concurrent?
Oh Noez.
Oh Noez.
```

However, I get the following output:

```
Is it concurrent?
Oh Noez.
Is it concurrent?
Oh Noez.
```

Which tells me, that capybara requests are not run at the same time, but one at a time. **How do I make my capabara requests concurrent?**

Comment: Your code example above doesn't look like the current Capybara DSL to me. It looks more like a plain controller test using Rack::Test. Is that what it is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Multithreading and capybara does not work, because Capabara uses a seperate server thread which handles connection sequentially. But if you fork, it works.

I am using exit codes as an inter-process communication mechanism. If you do more complex stuff, you may want to use sockets.

This is my quick and dirty hack:

```
before do
  @concurrent_requests = 2.times.map do
    fork do
      # ActiveRecord explodes when you do not re-establish the sockets
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!

      answer = post "/api/v1/item/buy.json", :id => item.id

      # Calling exit! instead of exit so we do not invoke any rspec's `at_exit`
      # handlers, which cleans up, measures code coverage and make things explode.
      case JSON.parse(answer.body)["status"]
        when "accepted"
          exit! 128
        when "too_late"
          exit! 129
      end
    end
  end

  # Wait for the two requests to finish and get the exit codes.
  @exitcodes = @concurrent_requests.map do |pid|
    Process.waitpid(pid)
    $?.exitstatus
  end

  # Also reconnect in the main process, just in case things go wrong...
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!

  # And reload the item that has been modified by the seperate processs,
  # for use in later `it` blocks.
  item.reload
end

it "should only accept one of two concurrent requests" do
  @exitcodes.sort.should == [128, 129]
end
```

I use rather exotic exit codes like *128* and *129*, because processes exit with code 0 if the case block is not reached and 1 if an exception occurs. Both should not happen. So by using higher codes, I notice when things go wrong.

Comment: Good workaround! Just as a reference, can you post the relevant controller/model code that manifested the race condition?

Comment: Can't believe this question and answer haven't been voted up yet. Saved my day!

Comment: "Multithreading and capybara does not work" This may have been true at the time of writing, but is very much false now. Capybara works great in a threaded environment as long as you explicitly initialize a separate Capybara::Session object for each thread, and use that one instead of the default session (ie. instead of just saying `visit url` say `@capybara.visit url`). See Tanzeeb's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

You can't make concurrent capybara requests. However, you can create multiple capybara sessions and use them within the same test to simulate concurrent users.

```
user_1 = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit) # or whatever driver
user_2 = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit)

user_1.visit 'some/page'
user_2.visit 'some/page'

# ... more tests ...

user_1.click_on 'Buy'
user_2.click_on 'Buy'
```

Comment: I knew about sequential requests. I finally solved the problem myself. See my answer. I **can** make concurrent requests.